# AWK System() Call w/Variable

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to display paragraphs from a text file that has entries like this:

```
<<<<<<o01o>>>>>>
CLAUSEID:000116
COMMENTS:
GENRES:
KEYWORDS:
LAST UPDATE:201405171224
CREATION DATE:201405171224
CLAUSE:VARIABLE MULTI 
LINE PARAGRAPH 
STARTS HERE 
<<<<<<o01o>>>>>>
CLAUSEID:000117
COMMENTS:
GENRES:
KEYWORDS:
LAST UPDATE:201405171224
CREATION DATE:201405171224
CLAUSE:THIS CAN BE ANY NUMBER 
OF LINES
```

What I would like to do is banner the first field, display fields 8 until the end of 
the record and then pause for me to type anything to continue..

`awk 'BEGIN{RS="<<<<<<o01o>>>>>>";FS="\n"};{system("banner " $2); for(i=8;i<NF;i++) print $i; system("read i;clear")}' auto_contract_data1.txt`

Updated: The problem is that this will only give me an error on the first record for banner and the rest of the entries see only CLAUSEID: 0 instead of the proper values.

Final solution: `awk 'BEGIN{RS="<<<<<<o01o>>>>>>";FS="\n"} /CLAUSEID/{system("banner " substr($2,10)); for(i=8;i<NF;i++) if(i==8) print substr($i,8);else print $i; system("read i;clear")}' auto_contract_data1.txt`

@EdMorton: I tested your theory about globbing characters and it still works flawlessly, here is the data I used:

```
<<<<<<o01o>>>>>>
CLAUSEID:0001.1^@6
COMMENTS:
GENRES:
KEYWORDS:
LAST UPDATE:201405171224
CREATION DATE:201405171224
CLAUSE:VARIAB*LE MULTI 
LINE PAR-AG&RAP?H 
STARTS HERE 
<<<<<<o01o>>>>>>
CLAUSEID:000117
COMMENTS:
GENRES:
KEYWORDS:
LAST UPDATE:201405171224
CREATION DATE:201405171224
CLAUSE:THI$ CAN BE ^%#(*#$NY NUMBER 
OF LINE-.?S
```

@EdMorton: If you have a valid case please let me know.

Comment: I could have used a shell script but I wanted to use Awk since I'm starting to learn it now and it is a bit more powerful than Bash string manipulation. What input values would make this fail?

Comment: Like I said I wanted to use awk because of the string manipulation features - I also prefer one-liners over putting things into fluffy script files.

Comment: I see you edited your question to ask for an example of ways in which it could fail - if you ever want someone to re-look at your question you need to leave them a comment, I just saw your update by chance when I was deleting my previous comments as I thought you were ignoring them.

Comment: Create an empty directory, cd to it and execute the script `awk 'BEGIN{var="foo*"; system("echo " var)}'` and it will output `foo*`. Now create a file named `foobar` in that same directory and execute that same script again and this time it's output will be `foobar`. The same will happen for your call to `system("banner " var)`. This is not the only potential failure.

Comment: Thats interesting doesn't seem to apply to my script but I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: By `doesn't seem to apply to my script` I assume you mean the one example I gave. Well - a) yes it does, and b) that's just one example of one type of failure. Also in terms of layers of calls you have `shell->awk->system->shell->banner` instead of `shell->{awk, banner}`. That alone can't seem right. I feel like we're flogging a dead horse though so - good luck with your script!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$1` is empty because the record separator `<<<<<<o01o>>>>>>` is always immediately followed by a field separator `\n`.  Try:

```
RS="<<<<<<o01o>>>>>>\n"
```

This way, `$1` will be the line which follows the `RS`.

Or, you can use `banner $2`.  However, since only displays 10 characters, consider:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="<<<<<<o01o>>>>>>";FS="\n"} /CLAUSEID/{system("banner " substr($2,10)); for(i=8;i<NF;i++) print $i; system("read i;clear")}' auto_contract_data1.txt
```

Note also the new condition `/CLAUSEID/` which assures that the first empty record is ignored.

#### Further improvement by A.Danischewski:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="<<<<<<o01o>>>>>>";FS="\n"} /CLAUSEID/{system("banner " substr($2,10)); for(i=8;i<NF;i++) if(i==8) print substr($i,8);else print $i; system("read i;clear")}' autocontract.txt
```

Comment: Yea I put the $1 down it should be $2, I will update it but it still doesnt work for reason, it throws an error and then prints CLAUSEID 0 for both. Seems strange to me.

Comment: @A.Danischewski I checked the documentation for banners and it says it "prints out the first 10 characters of text in large letters."  That is why you only see `CLAUSEID:0`

Comment: Thanks, almost there - its working except for the first record: $ awk 'BEGIN{RS="<<<<<<o01o>>>>>>";FS="\n"};{system("banner -w 125 " $2); for(i=8;i<NF;i++) print $i; system("read i;clear")}' autocontract.txt

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{RS="<<<<<<o01o>>>>>>";FS="\n"} /CLAUSEID/{system("banner " substr($2,10)); for(i=8;i<NF;i++) if(i==8) print substr($i,8);else print $i; system("read i;clear")}' autocontract.txt -- your idea one step further and its done! =)

Answer (score 0):

This uses awk for what it's good at (i.e. text manipulation like selecting fields, substrings, etc) and shell for what it's good at (sequencing calls to tools like awk, banner, etc. and reading user input):

```
awk '
BEGIN{ RS="<<<<<<o01o>>>>>>"; FS="\n" }
NF {
    sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    print "HDR", substr($2,10)
    print "TXT", substr($8,8)
    for(i=9;i<=NF;i++) {
        print "TXT", $i
    }
}' file |
while read -r type line
do
    case $type in
        HDR ) read i < /dev/tty; banner "$line" ;;
        * )   printf "%s\n" "$line" ;;
    esac
done
```